# How to plot hours with AM/PM in order from early to late in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
head(CaloriesNew1)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
          id activitydate activityhourampm calories
       <dbl> <chr>        <chr>               <dbl>
1 1503960366 4/12/2016    12:00:00 AM            81
2 1503960366 4/12/2016    1:00:00 AM             61
3 1503960366 4/12/2016    2:00:00 AM             59
4 1503960366 4/12/2016    3:00:00 AM             47
5 1503960366 4/12/2016    4:00:00 AM             48
6 1503960366 4/12/2016    5:00:00 AM             48
```

When I plot this, it doesn't arrange the x axis from the earliest time(12am) to the latest(11pm). It plots the data in ascending numerical order (1am, 1pm, 10am, 10pm, 11am, 11pm, etc...)

This is how I wrote it:

```
CaloriesNew1 %>% 
  ggplot(data = CaloriesNew1, mapping = aes(x = activityhourampm, y = calories))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

How can I plot this so the x axis will start from 12am, 1am, 2am, 3am.....10pm, 11pm)??? Would I need to change the data and format to a 24 hour format? If so, how can I do that?

This is how my chart looks now:

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of lubridate? It's great and I guess you would find a lot of great stuff
https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/

Comment: I have, but since I'm new I'll have to reread and practice. I was trying to stay away from reformatting the column to a 24-hour format because I want the AM/PM to still be there. But I guess I may have to reformat. Is there any way I can still do this without changing to 24-hour format?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get 12 hour clocks. With this, your data are at least ordered according to time.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# Read in data. I added a few lines to get PM hours.
df1 <- read.delim("clipboard", sep=" ")

df1
 x         id activitydate activityhourampm calories
 1 1503960366   2016-04-12         00:00:00       81
 2 1503960366   2016-04-12         01:00:00       61
 3 1503960366   2016-04-12         02:00:00       59
 4 1503960366   2016-04-12         03:00:00       47
 5 1503960366   2016-04-12         04:00:00       48
 6 1503960366   2016-04-12         05:00:00       48
 7 1503960366   2016-04-12         12:00:00       78
 8 1503960366   2016-04-12         14:00:00       88
 9 1503960366   2016-04-12         16:00:00       68
10 1503960366   2016-04-12         18:00:00       58
11 1503960366   2016-04-12         19:00:00       88
12 1503960366   2016-04-12         21:00:00       98

# Parse the date and time.
df1$activitydate <- parse_date(df1$activitydate, "%m/%d/%Y")
df1$activityhourampm <- parse_time(df1$activityhourampm, '%H:%M:%S %p')

# A plot like yours
df1 %>% 
  ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = activityhourampm, y = calories))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=45))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't figure out the 12 hour time format, so I just changed to 24 hour format and plotted that way. Thanks tho!